# mutate new column contains grepl values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have data.table like this:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(NA, "2019-08-02", NA, "243", "N"),
                b = c(NA, NA, "2", "2019-02-01", "MA"),
                c = c("2019-12-02", NA, "2019-11-22", NA, "2019-01-30"))
```

Values that i need are contained in different rows and columns. So, what i want?
I need to create new column, than contains my needed value:

```
1 2019-08-02 NA NA 242
2 2019-02-01 M 342 NA
3 2019-02-01 M 342 NA
4 2019-02-01 M 342 NA
5 2019-02-01 M 342 NA
```

I try to use `mutate_all`, but this function can't work with simple mutate!

```
data1 <- data %>% 
   mutate(new = mutate_all(., ~grepl("2019", .)))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the desired output? There is no 242 in the original data, and only one 243. You can easily put all the dates in one column. I am not sure what you would like to do with the rest of the data.

Comment: I have messy dataset with 3k rows and 20 columns)
so, manual work isn't very good)

Comment: Manual work is never good, I never mentioned it. Do you just need the dates in one column? Please answer directly in your quesion. I think it isnt too clear what your desired output is. Where do all the 342 come from in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you just want the dates in one column, this could work (assuming you have only one date per row):

```
library(stringr)
f <- apply(data, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "))
data$new <- str_extract(f, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")

data
           a          b          c        new
1       <NA>       <NA> 2019-12-02 2019-12-02
2 2019-08-02       <NA>       <NA> 2019-08-02
3       <NA>          2 2019-11-22 2019-11-22
4        243 2019-02-01       <NA> 2019-02-01
5          N         MA 2019-01-30 2019-01-30
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `tidyverse` is to reshape into 'long' format, `filter` the rows with `Date` format and bind the column to original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE, values_to = 'new')  %>% 
    select(new) %>% 
    filter(str_detect(new, "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$")) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  a          b          c          new       
#  <fct>      <fct>      <fct>      <fct>     
#1 <NA>       <NA>       2019-12-02 2019-12-02
#2 2019-08-02 <NA>       <NA>       2019-08-02
#3 <NA>       2          2019-11-22 2019-11-22
#4 243        2019-02-01 <NA>       2019-02-01
#5 N          MA         2019-01-30 2019-01-30
```

---

Or another option is to change the non-Date elements to `NA` and use `coalesce`

```
data %>% 
     mutate_all(~ as.character(replace(., !str_detect(., '^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$'), NA))) %>%
     transmute(new  = coalesce(!!! .)) %>%
     bind_cols(data, .)
#           a          b          c        new
#1       <NA>       <NA> 2019-12-02 2019-12-02
#2 2019-08-02       <NA>       <NA> 2019-08-02
#3       <NA>          2 2019-11-22 2019-11-22
#4        243 2019-02-01       <NA> 2019-02-01
#5          N         MA 2019-01-30 2019-01-30
```